# I am/have been busy (Present Simple/Cont vs Present Perfect Cont)

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense, present-continuous

Let's suppose I am saying these sentences on Thursday

> 1. I am really busy this week
> 2. I have been really busy this week

Sentence 1 I believe implies *"I am busy today and I will likely be busy all the other days until the end of the week"*.

While sentence 2 implies that *"I was busy on Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday and I am still busy today"*, however, it doesn't give any hints about the next 3 days of the week.

Is my understanding correct?

If so, can the same logic be applied to the following examples?:

> 3. Messi is playing really well this season
> 4. Messi has been playing really well this season

I understand that both 3 and 4 mean pretty much the same thing, but I wonder if there is any difference in terms of shades of meaning?  Also, what are the most common conversation scenarios for 3 and 4? Are they different or the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) I have commitments every day this week (including Friday and maybe Saturday).

(2) I haven't had a spare moment so far this week.

The same doesn't necessarily apply to another person's performance that you have no control over. You might say that Messi has been playing **well** [so far] this season if you think/fear he may be starting to play less well - otherwise they both mean the same.